# Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы функция в WordPress срабатывала только на определенной странице?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вообщем, вопрос такой. В вордпрессе есть такая функция:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'generate_add_viewport' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'generate_add_viewport' );
    /**
     * Add viewport to wp_head.
     *
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    function generate_add_viewport() {
        echo apply_filters( 'generate_meta_viewport', '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( is_page( $page ) ){
    //code goes here
}
```

Вероятно, можно 
`add_action( 'wp_head', 'generate_add_viewport' );` поставить в это условие, можно условие в код функции добавить. Не могу сказать как верно будет, с WP достаточно давно работал, "не пользовался" подобным.
`$page` - можно передавать id страницы, можно slug, можно title, можно массив с элементами. Если slug состоит с кирилицы (пример, о-сайте) то не забывайте обернуть  его в `sanitize_title()`

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо!) В итоге получился такой код:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'generate_add_viewport' ) ) {
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'generate_add_viewport' );

/**
 * Add viewport to wp_head.
 *
 * @since 1.1.0
 */

function generate_add_viewport() {
     if( is_page(21) ) {

 }
 else {
    echo apply_filters( 'generate_meta_viewport', '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
      }
 }
}
```

где 21 - это номер страницы,

Comment: если вам надо исключить страницу то делайте так:

Comment: `if( !is_page(21) ) { echo apply_filters( 'generate_meta_viewport', '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' ); }`

Comment: Я создал "велосипед"?)

Comment: в подобных случаях принято ставить "отрицание" и сразу в теле писать, а не оставлять пустое тело и добавлять блок else

Comment: Так, а если мой способ функционирует корректно, то насколько он примерно замедляет загрузку?

Comment: Я не говорю что он не работает, так не принято делать и это слегка глупо (небольшая неуместная глупая аналогия - вы чтобы купить коробку спичек берёте с собой дорожную сумку? вот, как-то так это выглядит со стороны). Предложенный мною вариант, так же, работает, и так принято делать. Ну а насчет "замедляет" то в вашем примере ничего не замедляется, трудно это сделать когда нагрузки то нет

Comment: Ладно, понял, большое спасибо за помощь.